# Detecting features in XY Plots using CNNs

Tags: neural-network, cnn

I have a simple classification problem - if two features plotted on a simple XY plot show a "kink" or characteristic turn, then the label is TRUE, otherwise FALSE.  I've been attempting to detect the "kinks" in these plots using fully-connected NN's without much success.  I thought about converting my XY plots into images, and then feeding them into a CNN, but that seems to be fairly inefficient.  Does anyone have any advice for this situation?  A kink is circled below.  Thanks

[image: XY plot with characteristic kink]

Comment: Surely it's easier to learn this directly on the data, not in a plot of the data?

Comment: @SeanOwen - so I would think you're right.  I'm trying to think through how to convert specific XY plots to an input shape that a CNN could digest...

Comment: I suppose it depends on what a 'kink' is here; I don't see any turn in the region you circled. If they're the un-smooth regions, just sort by X and find subsequences where variance of Y is high. that kind of thing might get what you want more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit surprised that fully connected neural networks are unable to learn this. It might be due to one or more of the many possible problems like few data or overparameterisation.

Keeping this aside, your problem seems to be solvable by tree classifiers like CART, Random Forest, Gradient Boosting Machine or XGBoost.

The reason I think tree methods can work is that the problem can be solved using a decision tree. To detect the kinks one needs to find whether the datapoint is below the red line within some specific range of X and Y. Once the kink is detected it is easier to predict TRUE or FALSE as you mentioned.

Comment: Hey I appreciate the response, and the model I have in production now actually does use an ensemble approach of tree-based models.  However, the kink does not really lend itself to rule-based detection.  It does not occur at any fixed, repeatable locations, and can easily be located outside the bouds of my training set.

Comment: Oh I see. Still if the data has the information needed to solve the problem then I think the tree model should be able to estimate the range where the kink should occur based on some other condition which can be learned from the information in the data. I think that is why your ensemble too might be giving better performance than the CNN and fully connected neural networks.

Comment: For sure - and you may be right.  I was learning about CNNs and I was thinking that might be an alternate approach that would be more accurate, but  may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think what doesn't help the learning of a fully connected NN is that so many of your data point are highly correlated, though if you had enough examples, it should be able to work it out.
Try to apply some dimensionality reduction like PCA to reduce the size of your NN and try again.

Another idea might be to feature engineer your data a little bit. The definition of a spike in my book is a spike in the 2nd derivative. So difference your data twice and train the model to detect spikes, which should be easier. "Differencing" is to replace your data `x0, x1, x2, ...` by `x1-x0, x2-x1,  ...` and you need to apply that procedure twice to get the second derivative.